# Merge [web-crawler] [webcrawling] [crawler] [spider] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

- [web-crawler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) x 20
- [spider](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spider) x 12
- [webcrawling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webcrawling) x 6
- [crawler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crawler) x 5

They're all identical and refer to [**Web crawler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler):

> Other terms for Web crawlers are ants, automatic indexers, bots,
>   Web spiders, Web robots, or—especially in the FOAF community—Web
>   scutters.

I think that [webcrawling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webcrawling), [crawler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crawler) and [spider](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spider) should be merged into [web-crawler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler).
Can we merge and synonymize them?

Comment: I agree, they all seem to be synonyms.

Comment: My only very slight doubt would be if there is a difference in usage - 'my site is crawled' vs 'I send out a spider' (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged all of these. "Spider" didn't seem to have a different meaning, and in fact, most of the web crawling quesiton were tagged with "spider" anyway.